# javascript function with multiple arrow "=>" parameters

Tags: javascript, redux, middleware, arrow-functions, function-parameter

I was reading about redux middle ware and I noticed a below function. As you see, it has three "=>". Can someone please explain how does these three "=>" work?

```
const logger = store => next => action => {
  console.log('dispatching', action)
  let result = next(action)
  console.log('next state', store.getState())
  return result
}
```

Can we pass these parameters in parenthesis as below instead?

```
const logger = (store, next, action) => {
 ... ... ...
 ... ... ...
}
```

Comment: `logger` is a function which returns a function which returns a function which returns a function.

Comment: *"Can we pass these parameters in parenthesis as below instead?"* -- No, those are not synonymous lines of code.